# Getting substrings from constantly changing string

Tags: java, android, string

So I will cut down the explanation why I need it but will go straight to the point. My application is receiving an `InputStream` of type `String`. This message of `InputString` is placed into the `ArrayAdapter<String>` later on. It looks let's say like this:

```
$VER,1,8,06351.0,1207.1,N,13516.4,E,0.03,165.48,5,4,-300,0,100,500,2000,1100,500,23.1,49,1012.111,2.9,2.9,2.9,2.9,1,*FFFF\n
```

where `$VER,` is always at the start of that string while all the values are changing constantly. The commas `,` are separating various values where each of them is very important. So basically I can not predict how will the value look - it can be `1.4` or `1234` or even letter. This way I can not work on the length of the string using `substring` as commas can land on various places, counting from the start.

What would be the most sufficient and best way of extracting each of this value so I could separately put them into `TextViews` of my own?

Comment: you can use some regular expression matcher like  this : 
//matches numbers only 
String regexStr = "^[0-9]*$"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)?

```
String s = "$VER,1,8,06351.0,1207.1,N,13516.4,E,0.03,165.48,5,4,-300,0,100,500,2000,1100,500,23.1,49,1012.111,2.9,2.9,2.9,2.9,1,*FFFF";
String[] a = s.split(",");
```

Remember to use `Pattern.quote` if you ever need to use this to split on strings that contain the special regular expression characters.

```
String[] b = s.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

Comment: If that solves my problem, surely I am :D Checking soon.

Comment: Note that `"\\."` is the same regex as `Pattern.quote(".")` will return. This might be relevant if you mix ordinary any-dots with escaped dots.

Comment: @StackOverflowException - not quite - on my setup it produces `\Q.\E` but your point is valid, "\\." will also defeat the specialness of the "." character.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: Okay, sure. It means the same but is more efficient for longer sequences. I just wanted to prevent that "Oh, why did nobody tell me?" moment...